# DB2 and Report Studio: convert string date to numeric

Tags: db2, report, cognos

I have a date in this format: Jan 1, 2013 (taken from the date prompt in report studio)

I want to convert it to a timestamp using sql(db2) or a report studio command, the output should look like this: 1130101000000000

Appreciate your inputs.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()` scalar function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html).  I'm honestly not sure what your format there actually is (1 + 2 digit year + 2 digit month + 2 digit day + hours/minutes/second/microseconds ?), but the Info Center page I linked should give you enough information to get what you want. Maybe something like

```sql
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(your_date, 'YYMMDDHHMISSFN3')
FROM your_table
```

Comment: I leave this link as it helped too http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html